# Google App Engine Search API, searching in multiple indexes

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Since GAE 1.9 release the search API indexes are limited to 10 GB data only. so the problem is if we have to save data more than this limit then we will have to spread it in multiple indexes and we will have to do queries in multiple indexes. Is there any way to perform search in multiple indexes?

Comment: Did you find any additional information about this?

Comment: No, i had to implement a polling based asynchronous search

Comment: So you mean multiple queries based on your app logic to retrieve results in multiple steps?